# Shared segment memory writing random numbers

Tags: c, memory, process, buffer, shared

I am having an issue with logic with my C program. I am trying to make a process which writes to a memory buffer like 10 random numbers and inside a text file too. I have that already as you will see in my code but I can't seem to understand how to use the shared memory to do this.

I'm trying to understand that I have to define a buffer size first and store id into an item then I have to store my random numbers inside that item array. Am I thinking something wrong?
Am I missing something on my logic?

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main()
{

    int i, n;
    time_t t;

     n = 10;

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen ("letter.txt","a+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf ("File not created okay, errno = %d\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }
    for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
        fprintf(fp,"%d\n", rand() % 10);


        /* here is where I would store the random numbers in the buffer */
    }

    fclose (fp);
    printf ("File created okay\n");
    scanf();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Which platform are you using?  Which function calls for managing the shared memory segment on that platform?  (There are at least two sets of shared memory calls, plus `mmap()`, available on POSIX systems, for example.)  What have you actually tried?  Pro tip: add the randomization after you can write deterministic data to shared memory.  It's difficult to spot whether what you're doing is correct when the data is random.  How are you planning to check what you've written to shared memory?  Hint: shared memory usually involves several processes that share access to a single chunk of memory.

Comment: Note that the `scanf()` call with zero arguments is a disaster waiting to happen. You need at least the format string argument.

Comment: oh i seee, let my change my scanf then and im using windows but also im using a debian vm inside my computer  and using putty and nano to write inside debian... so to have a chunk of memoryused by two or more process i have to point to the same memory address?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared memory in multiple processes within the VM, but you would not be able to share memory between processes running in the VM and processes running in the host O/S, Windows.  If the VM is running Debian, then you need to use one of:

1. [`mmap()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html).
2. [`shmget()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmget.html),
   [`shmctl()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmctl.html),
   [`shmat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmat.html),
   [`shmdt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmdt.html) — the 'System V IPC' shared memory calls.
3. [`shm_open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html),
   [`shm_unlink()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_unlink.html) — the more recent, more POSIX-like, shared memory calls.

You will probably need two programs that connect to the same shared memory segment.  It is likely that they'll map the segment to the same address.  If you store pointers in the shared memory, it is crucial that they are mapped to the same address.  If you store offsets relative to the base address of the shared memory segment, then it is not crucial that they're mapped to the same address.